# Webpack, build one JSON file from multiple JSON files at build time

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have to build a landing page which when visited will check your User Agent and determine which device you are using and if you are using a device that is supported it will show some information for that device. The information that is shown does not matter that's done, checking User Agent is also done.

What is not done is this because I am stuck. I have directory structure like this:

```
-devices
 -nintendo
  config.json
 -xbox
  config.json
 -ps5
  config.json
```

and so on. So since I need to access these configs at runtime since I will not know which device the user is using until they land on the page, this cannot be determined at build time. So my thoughts are have a JS file that will loop through all of these folders and take each config and build one big config that will be a module in web pack that I can import in my main.js file so I can than just import it and access the properties using dot notation.

Can I do all of this with web pack and skip the JS file that will combine all of the config, or is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need anything extra to achieve this. Assuming you have following directory structure:

```
- main.js
- devices
  - nintendo
    - config.json
  - xbox
    - config.json
  - ps5
    - config.json
```

All you have to do is to import individual JSONs in your `main.js` file:

```
import nintendo from './devices/nintendo/config.json';
import xbox from './devices/xbox/config.json';
import ps5 from './devices/ps5/config.json';


function main() {

  // Read `someDevice` at runtime

  if (someDevice === 'nintendo') {
    console.log(nintendo);
  }

}
```

If your `json` files are big and bundle size becomes a concern, then you can use dynamic imports along with **async-await** and Webpack will automatically split the bundle for you:

```
async function main() {

  if (someDevice === 'nintendo') {
    const nintendo = await import('./devices/nintendo/config.json');
  } else if (someDevice === 'xbox') {
    const xbox = await import('./devices/nintendo/config.json');
  } else {
    const ps5 = await import('./devices/ps5/config.json');
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and the first one will be a little redundant having static imports and only one import will be used. Because I could have 20 different configs/devices I need to check for and the list could continue growing. The dynamic imports might work but the if block will be quite big.

Comment: @thecbm123. The big `if-else` block is not the problem. But if you find it problematic, then just use the object where keys are `nintendo`, `xbox`, etc. and values are the dynamic import promises. So your code would be simply `return myObject[someDevice]`.